# Creating a singly linked list with an x and y minimum and maximum range in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list using a minimum and maximum value. This may be a really stupid way of doing this, and maybe I should be using a vector to accomplish what I want to do.

I'm having a really hard time inserting, I have no idea why this is not working, I have poured the internet, looked in my books, but nothing is getting this to work. Maybe it's because I am using smart pointers and I am not 100% confident with using them yet but here is my Node:

```
struct Node
{
    Node(int m = 0, int M = 0, std::shared_ptr<Node> r = nullptr) : min(m), max(M), right(r){}
    std::shared_ptr<Node> right;

    int min;
    int max;
};
```

I believe this is set up correctly, but here is my insert Function, and I am certain this is the problem. And I am not sure if this should be a void function, or if it should be a std::shared_ptr

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> Container::insert(std::shared_ptr<Node> list, int min, int max) 
{

    if(!list)
    {
        list = std::make_shared<Node>(min, max);
    }

    list->right = insert(list->right, min, max);
    return list;

}
```

I'm kind of at a lost here, and maybe I'm just not understanding the problem well enough. Basically, I just want to be able to compare minimums and maximums. Again, it just might be a really bad way that I am approaching the problem.

Comment: If you call `insert()` inside the `insert()` function, won't that keep looping forever?

Comment: If you would use the STL implementation it would look like `std::list<std::pair<int, int>>`. Though writing your own implementation is a useful exercise you should familiarize yourself with the STL, so try doing the same using the STL containers :)

Comment: @Rerito, I have never heard of STL containers, I'm going to have to look those up and see how they work.

Comment: Begin by browsing [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected the code by adding the base case of your recursion.

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> Container::insert(std::shared_ptr<Node>& list, int min, int max) 
{

    if(!list)
    {
        list = std::make_shared<Node>(min, max);
    }else{
        list->right = insert(list->right, min, max);
    }

    return list;

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I went ahead and made the changes, and for whatever reason, it is not reaching the else statement. I put an std::cout statement inside the else statement and it is not printing out what I told it to print out. If I put the std::cout statement inside the if statement, then it will print something out.

Comment: @Sailanarmo, result depends on what you are feeding. I ca not tell anything unless you show all parts of the code.

Comment: here is a link to my github which has my current code on it. https://github.com/Sailanarmo/Group-Algorithm

Comment: I figured it out! I have to take the pointer by reference! Once I added that I was able to move on in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You're recursing unconditionally, so will never terminate.

Assuming that you want to insert a new node at the end of `list`, it should probably be

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> Container::insert(std::shared_ptr<Node> list, int min, int max) 
{
    if(!list)
    {
        list = std::make_shared<Node>(min, max);
    }
    else
    {
        list->right = insert(list->right, min, max);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Yeesh, who knew that the else statement was really needed. I feel like and idiot now. Now I just need to try and print this out which I am guessing my method of doing so is also wrong.

Comment: @Sailanarmo You can print using the same general formula. Structural recursion over lists is usually uncomplicated; most of the time you can first write `if (!list) { ... } else { ... }`, then fill in the two cases and then you're done.

Comment: Which I just did, I put `if(!min) std::cout << "The list is empty" <<std::endl;` else `std::cout << list->right << " "; printMin(list->right)` and it tells me that the list is empty.

Comment: @Sailanarmo Because it is. You could say `head = insert(head, min, max);` in the constructor.